# Map Integer Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use a predefined integer to integer python dictionary in order to map the corresponding rows in a pandas dataframe to a new row without success.

I have the following dataframe:

```
data=np.array([
    ['Item 1',7365301,"Cool item."]
])

items = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['name','id','description'])
```

I have a python dictionary, that maps from int->int like so:

```
item_map = {7365301: 10}
```

I am trying to map the values in my dictionary to a new column by using Pandas `map` like:

```
items['id2'] = items['id'].map(inverse_item_map)
```

which ends up with the following:

```
    name    id  description id2
0   Item 1  7365301 Cool item.  NaN
```

or like:

```
items['id2'] = items['id'].map(inverse_item_map).astype(int)
```

which throws a ValueError:

```
Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

What's going on here? Am I doing something wrong here? Why is this operation unsuccessful?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, is you passing the value by using `np.array` , it will not support multiple type, which means if there is str it will convert all number to str as well.

Check the data

```
data=np.array([
    ['Item 1',7365301,"Cool item."]
])
data
                            #str
Out[16]: array([['Item 1', '7365301', 'Cool item.']], dtype='<U10')
```

That is why you id become str type

```
items.applymap(type)
Out[14]: 
            name             id    description
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

I will recommend change `item_map = {7365301: 10}` to item_map = `{'7365301': 10}`

Then

```
items['id2'] = items['id'].map(inverse_item_map).astype(int)
```

Comment: You can embed some safeguards with a clever lambda `map(lambda k: inverse_item_map.get(int(k), 0))`